# Filtering on loadData using POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, xmlhttprequest, jsgrid

The grid is not filtered when I use POST request

```
loadData: function (filter) {
  return $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "frmNewGroup.aspx/searchFilter",
  data: JSON.stringify(filter),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Do we have to use GET request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `def.resolve(data);` when you get data from ajax.

```
loadData : function(filter) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
          url: "frmNewGroup.aspx/searchFilter",
          data: JSON.stringify(filter),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            def.resolve(data);
        });
        return def.promise();
    }
```

Comment: Still not filtered.. it shows “Not found” message. And I’m pretty sure that I have some returned data.

Comment: Sorry, I was returning $.ajax instead of def. now it works. Thank you do much!